# Telerik window not loading on first click attempt of an asp linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Issue: on click of asp link button does not open Telerik window, thereafter it loads as expected. Issue occurs only on the first time clicking. Following is the code:

> 1. Manage.aspx [Asp link button invoking Add_Click]

```
`<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnAddRole" runat="server" OnClick="Add_Click"></asp:LinkButton>`
```

> 2. Manage.aspx.cs [Add_Click method invoking Telerik window from code behind]

```
 protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Load", "openRadWindow('../Admin/ConfigForm.aspx', 'TelRadWindowVersion1');", true);
}
```

> 3. Manage.aspx [Telerik window with appropriate properties]

```
 <telerik:RadWindow ID="TelRadWindowVersion1" AutoSize="false" runat="server" VisibleStatusbar="false"
                Modal="true" Behaviors="Close, Resize" ReloadOnShow="true" CenterIfModal="true" Height="490"
                Width="700" OnClientClose="myfunc" />
```

> 4. OnClientClose will invoke the following:-

```
 <script>       
        function myfunc() {
            <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(listRefresh, String.Empty) %>;
            window["<%= updnlist.ClientID %>"].submit;
        }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure your openRadWindow function is actually called every time you need it to be
2. Ensure you are using the Sys.Application.Load event to execute your script so it does not execute too early
3. Ensure you are getting a correct reference to the desired object via $find()

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, will surely try the said above.